# ggplot Bar Chart - Label every x-value and remove missing observations

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar plot in R using ggplot, displaying the year a document was published as an x-variable and a mean_sentiment score of that document on the y-axis.

However, I am pretty new to R and there are two problems that I cannot figure out:

1. The x-axis reporting the year is labelled in 10-year steps. I however, want every bar labelled with the respective year.
2. There are some years for which there is no data. In my current version, these missing years are left blank. I want to erase that space (do I have to treat the year variable as a factor somehow?)

Thank you very much for any help, I'm a little lost here.

```
library(ggplot2)

sent_results$posneg_label <- ifelse(sent_results$mean_sentiment < 0, "Negative", "Positive") 

ggplot(sent_results, aes(year, mean_sentiment)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill=posneg_label)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Mean Sentiment towards China", 
                    labels = c("Positive", "Negative"), 
                    values = c("Positive"="green", "Negative"="red"))
```

Comment: What's the output of `str(sent_results)`? Have you tried converting `year` to factor, as you suggested yourself? Was there any problem with that approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, for (1) you just need to do `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(first_year, last_year, by = 1)`

For (2), indeed treating year as a factor would be an efficient solution (and then you don't need to do the above code). If you wrap your year aes like this: `factor(year)` you should get what you want.